# certificate issue when I use ruby imap to read icloud email

Tags: ruby

When I tried to read icloud email using Net::IMAP, I got:

```
in 'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to turn off peer verification globally:

`OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`